# document.getElementbyId inside ion-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, ionic-framework

I have ion-view with ion-tabs inside. When I try to get canvas with

```
document.getElementById('photoCanvas');
```

I got 'undefined'. This is my code:

**HTML:**

```html
    <ion-view  name="photo" ng-init="loadPhotoToCanvas()">
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-left">
            <ion-tab title="Image" icon-on="ion-image" icon-off="ion-image">
                <ion-scroll delegate-handle="photoScroll" zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; height: 40em;">
                     <canvas id="photoCanvas" on-touch="canvasMouseDown($event)" on-release="canvasMouseUp($event)" on-drag="canvasMouseMove($event)">
                     </canvas>
                </ion-scroll>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-view>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.loadPhotoToCanvas = function(){
    $scope.canvas = document.getElementById('photoCanvas');
     //etc...
};
```

$scope.canvas here is undefined.

If I put canvas outside ion-tabs directive then getElementById works. This is working html:

```html
<ion-view  name="photo" ng-init="loadPhotoToCanvas()">
    <ion-scroll delegate-handle="photoScroll" zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; height: 40em;">
         <canvas id="photoCanvas" on-touch="canvasMouseDown($event)" on-release="canvasMouseUp($event)" on-drag="canvasMouseMove($event)">
         </canvas>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-view>
```

I believe that this problem is somehow related to ion-tabs directive. How can I get canvas from ion-tab? Is there something conceptually wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to listen for afterEnter event on ionicView. loadPhotoToCanvas method has been triggered before view has finished loading. This resolved my issue:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function (viewInfo, state) {
    $scope.loadPhotoToCanvas();
});
```

I have also removed ng-init from html since it is not required anymore.